# How to show information of a dynamically populated table into a popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a table which is populated like this

```
      $(document).ready(function (e) {
      var t = { Qty: [61.0, 0.0, 8.0], Name: ["2009 A", "2009 B", "2009 C "] }
         $.each(t.Qty, function (i, ele) {
           $("#content").append("<tr><td><input type='radio' /></td><td>"+parseFloat(t.Qty[i]).toFixed(1) + "</td><td>" + t.Name[i] + "</td></tr>");
    })
})
```

and its html code

```
  <script   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js">          </script>
     <table>
        <thead>
           <tr>
              <th>Select </th>
              <th>Qty</th>
               <th>Name</th>
       </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="content">
</tbody>
```

I have to show the table information  i.e name and qty in a popup whichever radio button is clicked.I am new to jquery.Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could easy bind on change state of radio buttons in table with:

```
$('#content').on('change', 'input[type="radio"]', function(){ /*code*/ });
```

and inside of it check is this radio checked?

```
if ($(this).is(':checked')) { /* code */ }
```

To get text from table, you have to select parent `tr` of input radio that is clicked, and inside of that tr you got, you have to search tds, with jquery `.find('td:eq(NUMBER_OF_TD)')` .
TD elements starts from zero (0).

```js
$(document).ready(function (e) {
      var t = { Qty: [61.0, 0.0, 8.0], Name: ["2009 A", "2009 B", "2009 C "] }
         $.each(t.Qty, function (i, ele) {
           $("#content").append("<tr><td><input type='radio' /></td><td>"+parseFloat(t.Qty[i]).toFixed(1) + "</td><td>" + t.Name[i] + "</td></tr>");
    })
         
    $('#content').on('change', 'input[type="radio"]', function(){
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
          
        var table_Name = $(this).parents('tr').find('td:eq(2)').text(); 
        var table_Quantity = $(this).parents('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text(); 
        
        alert("Name: "+table_Name+" & Quantity: "+table_Quantity);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js">          </script>
     <table>
        <thead>
           <tr>
              <th>Select </th>
              <th>Qty</th>
               <th>Name</th>
       </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="content">
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It uses jquery ui to show popup window

your HTML code

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Select </th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="content">
    </tbody>
</table>

<div id='popup' style='display: none;'>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Qty</td><td><label id='lblQty'></label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Name</td><td><label id='lblName'></label></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

and javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  var t = {
    Qty: [61.0, 0.0, 8.0],
    Name: ["2009 A", "2009 B", "2009 C "]
  }
  $.each(t.Qty, function(i, ele) {
    $("#content").append("<tr><td><input type='radio' name='my_radio' ind='"+i+"' /></td><td>" + parseFloat(t.Qty[i]).toFixed(1) + "</td><td>" + t.Name[i] + "</td></tr>");
  });
  $('#content [type=radio]').click(function open_popup(e){
    $('#popup').dialog({
        open: function(){
        $(this).find('#lblQty').text(parseFloat(t.Qty[$(e.currentTarget).attr('ind')]).toFixed(1));
        $(this).find('#lblName').text(t.Name[$(e.currentTarget).attr('ind')]);
      }
    });
  });

});
```

This is the working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Lurofvzn/